# Reverse expand with Emmet

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, emmet, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime Text and Emmet. And I was wandering if there is a way to convert some html code into emmet shortcuts? So to use Emmet in the other sens.

I didn't find anything on the web.

So from this :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

to this:

```
ul>li*3>a>i.fa.fa-user
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently it’s not possible. You can join the discussion for this feature request: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/93

Comment: Hum :( Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the extension "Reverse Emmet" from github:
https://github.com/jzmstrjp/brackets-reverse-emmet